# Hive: Deal with date types

Tags: sql, hive

Im new using hive.
I want to insert data on db1.tabl1.

**File.hql**

```
insert table db1.tb1 partition (dt_p= ${dt_p})
select f1, f2, ${date_temp}, ${dt_p}
from db2.tb1
```

db2.tb1 contaibs 3 columns(f1,f2,dt_p)
db1.tb1 contains 4 columns (f1, f2, dt_p, date_temp)
The column date_temp in db1.tb1 is of type string.

i declared date_temp = $(date -d "$1" +%Y-%m%dTH:%M:%S) in the sh file date_temp is the date passed as argument when launching the sh file that run the .hql where i put my hive code.

when launching my sh i got this error cannot recognize input near '15T16': '57'

I think that hive does not support T
who can help me please??